# How to connect android app with nosqlcloudant db Ibm bluemix service?

Tags: android, connection, ibm-cloud, cloudant

The problem is all tutorials I have explored so far is only for mobile cloud service.

Now they have migrated to MobileFirst..

So couldn't make it..

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you are trying to do? I am having the bluemix and cloudant tags added to your post to make it seen by the Bluemix community.

Comment: Need of, 1. Sensor collection android app, 2. Storing sensor values to ibm cloud

Comment: Does the answer below address your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetag sample connects to Bluemix Cloudant service and can run on Android natively when built with Cordova, or in a browser. https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluetag
Actually the Bluetag frontend javascript app  make REST calls to microservices and the services call Cloudant.   I don't suggest calling the Cloudant APIs directly from Android.